# QGIS GRASS error

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, grass-gis, qgis-processing, qgis-grass-plugin

I just installed QGIS 3 (after trashing the QGIS 2 app) on my macOS High Sierra. The application has been working well besides this error message that comes up when I try to use certain GRASS modules.

> /var/folders/__/1hf4c_j94db0r4mcfwlw694c0000gn/T/processing_70c3aacd8f614b74974418d6b27d7c60/grassdata/temp_location/PERMANENT: /Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/grass/etc/colors/grass: Permission denied
>
> /var/folders/__/1hf4c_j94db0r4mcfwlw694c0000gn/T/processing_70c3aacd8f614b74974418d6b27d7c60/grassdata/temp_location/PERMANENT: /Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/grass/etc/colors/grass: Permission denied

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known bug](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/17555) and has been [fixed](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/6676) in QGIS master.  The fix will be available in the [KyngChaos QGIS 3](https://www.kyngchaos.com/) app package in due course.